# How to share an Image using Airdrop from iPad mini to MacBook

Tags: file-sharing, airdrop

I am using an iPad Mini with iOS 7.1 , I want to share an image file using airdrop feature from my iPad mini to MacBook . But iPad mini is not detecting MacBook on Airdrop. How can I share file to and from iPad mini to MacBook using Airdrop??

Comment: Apple didnt apply the sharing part using "AirDrop" between IOS devices & OSX still yet to come..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AirDrop through iOS and OSX isn't supported yet.
(source: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5887?viewlocale=en_EN&locale=en_EN)